# Calculating rolling correlation of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to use the rolling window and correlation function in pandas to do a correlation of a shorter dataframe or series to a longer one, and get the result along the longer time series?  Basically doing what the numpy.correlate method does, but instead of cross-correlation, doing pairwise correlations.

```
x= [0,1,2,3,4,5,4,7,6,9,10,5,6,4,8,7]
y= [4,5,4,5]
print(x)
print(y)
corrs = []
for i in range(0,len(x)-3):
    corrs.append( np.corrcoef(x[i:i+4],y)[0,1] )
```

with a result of:

```
[0.4472135954999579, 0.4472135954999579, 0.4472135954999579, 0.0, 0.8164965809277259, -0.4472135954999579, 0.8320502943378437, 0.0, -0.24253562503633297, 0.24253562503633297, -0.7683498199278325, 0.8451542547285166, -0.50709255283711]
```

Every combination of windows and pairwise either gives a series of NAN or a "ValueError: Length mismatch". In the simple test case I made, its always NAN or a single result, but no window.

```
x = pd.DataFrame(x)
y = pd.DataFrame(y)

corr = y.rolling(np.shape(y)[0]).corr(x)
print(corr)
corr = y.rolling(np.shape(x)[0]).corr(x)
print(corr)
corr = x.rolling(np.shape(x)[0]).corr(y)
print(corr)
corr = x.rolling(np.shape(y)[0]).corr(y)
print(corr)
corr = y.rolling(np.shape(y)[0]).corr(x,pairwise=True)
print(corr)
corr = y.rolling(np.shape(x)[0]).corr(x,pairwise=True)
print(corr)
corr = x.rolling(np.shape(x)[0]).corr(y,pairwise=True)
print(corr)
corr = x.rolling(np.shape(y)[0]).corr(y,pairwise=True)
print(corr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Rolling.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html) with `np.corrcoef` or with [`Series.corr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html) with same index values like `y` - so necessary [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
x= [0,1,2,3,4,5,4,7,6,9,10,5,6,4,8,7]
y= [4,5,4,5]

corrs = []
for i in range(0,len(x)-3):
    corrs.append( np.corrcoef(x[i:i+4],y)[0,1] )

x = pd.Series(x)
y = pd.Series(y)

corr1 = x.rolling(np.shape(y)[0]).apply(lambda x: np.corrcoef(x, y)[0,1], raw=True)
corr2 = x.rolling(np.shape(y)[0]).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True).corr(y), raw=False)
```

---

```
print (pd.concat([pd.Series(corrs).rename(lambda x: x + 3), corr1, corr2], axis=1))
           0         1         2
0        NaN       NaN       NaN
1        NaN       NaN       NaN
2        NaN       NaN       NaN
3   0.447214  0.447214  0.447214
4   0.447214  0.447214  0.447214
5   0.447214  0.447214  0.447214
6   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
7   0.816497  0.816497  0.816497
8  -0.447214 -0.447214 -0.447214
9   0.832050  0.832050  0.832050
10  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
11 -0.242536 -0.242536 -0.242536
12  0.242536  0.242536  0.242536
13 -0.768350 -0.768350 -0.768350
14  0.845154  0.845154  0.845154
15 -0.507093 -0.507093 -0.507093
```

Comment: corr1 example gives an error that all input array dimensions must match exactly

Comment: @user-2147482637 - Do you test `x = pd.Series(x)
y = pd.Series(y)` ?

Comment: I see, yes thats a problem, it doesnt work on dataframes

Comment: why does rolling correlation of the pandas library not work?

Comment: @user-2147482637 - Because it working only if same size of both Series

Comment: I found I can keep the x as a data frame and in the apply method do y.T and it works

Comment: Even if the data is the same size, the rolling window doesn't work, for example filling the rest with 0's.  Using the apply with this rolling window on numpy is really too slow.